# AlarmManager Being Triggered immediately because time occurs in the past

Tags: java, android

When launching my application, the AlarmManager is being triggered immediately because the time occurs in the past.

My idea was to check the actual time with the schedule one :

```
if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())); //where calendar is my scheduled calendar
```

If the above condition is true then:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
```

I think this will work.

However the confusion is at day 365:

If the scheduled time was before the Actual time, it will add one day according to this line: `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);` 
and it will become **1**

Doesn't that make it always in the past? Because there is no 366 ? Thus the AlarmManager will be always triggering it immediately considering it in the past?

EDIT:

Do you suggest I put instead :

```
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
```

Comment: AFAIK, `add()` on `DAY_OF_YEAR` will bump the year, but I retagged your question with `java` to hopefully get more input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CommonsWare's comment is correct; add() will add that amount of time and adjust all the fields appropriately.

The behavior you were concerned about would occur if you used roll() instead of add(). But you should be safe with add().

Here's the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) if you want to dig in further.